# String to date conversion

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Following code

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse("03-Apr-96"));
```

Gives output as `Wed Apr 03 00:00:00 IST 1996`

What should I do get the output like `1996-04-03 00:00:00.0`

Comment: you also need time or just date?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I need Date appended with 00:00:00.0

Comment: I have added a question at the bottom ,please suggest.I'm sorry for putting my question as an answer

Comment: Full reference of characters and examples are in SimpleDateFormat javadoc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DateFormat` object can be either used to parse a `String` into a `Date` object or the other way around. In your example, you're doing the former, when what you really want to do is to format your `Date` into a given pattern.

Here's an example of what you may want to do:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.print(df.format(yourDateObject));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
    Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse("03-Apr-96");  
    simpleDateFormat.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
        Date date=simpleDateFormat.parse("03-Apr-96");

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S", new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat1.format(date));
```